# Inserting international characters in strings

Tags: java, android

As soon as I try to assign a String variable in Android to a string with international characters (e.g. æ, ø, å) they are transformed into questions marks inside squares. Is there any way to support international characters, other than using string.xml, since that is not really a viable option, because I have an undetermined amount of strings generated.

Answer (score 0):

> they are transformed into questions marks inside squares

Ensure your source code file uses UTF-8 encoding and that should most likely be sufficient. Alternatively you can use codes (`\uHHHH`)